# PSEXEC error establishing communication with psexec service

Tags: psexec

I'm trying to run a program in system mode, but this error appears

> error establishing communication with psexec service computername

```
psexec \\kerjaTA -s "C:\Program Files\GOM\GOM.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

psexec connects to Windows service called "Server" that handles files/printers sharing.

Make sure that the hostname kerjaTA is accessible and you can connect using windows network client:

```
ping kerjaTA
net use \\kerjaTA
```

If this fails, try using ip address and make sure "Server" service is started on kerjaTA.

Comment: how i know "server" service is ON, in services or somewhere else? which one

Comment: Yes, in services. It's called "Server" (Name field in Services manager)

Comment: Server (already on), but error
psexec -s \\192.168.0.2 "path program"
my ip in ipconfig is 192.168.0.2